# Extracting data points between given limits using Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

```
Column A        Column B
5                         10
150                       200
```

The difference between Column A and Column B will tell you how many integers there are between the limits. Is there a formula to extract all these integers?

For example

- **Row 1** the numbers that lie within the range are: 6, 7, 8, 9.
- **Row 2** the numbers that lie within the range are: 151, 152, 153, 154, 155 ... 199.

Answer (score 1):

In `C1` and copied down as far as necessary and across on a row by row basis until no more numbers are visible:

```
=IF($A1+COLUMN()-2<$B1,$A1+COLUMN()-2,"")
```

Uses COLUMN to increment because the order start/finish complicates matters relative to stop/start (ie easier to deal with 10/5 and 200/150 than the other way around).

This reads "if the result of the calculation is less than the limit, display it, otherwise show [*blank*]. With 'the calculation' being add two less than the current column number (therefore 1) to start."